# How can ST_VoronoiPolygons be used instead of the broken built-in algorithm in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, voronoi-thiessen

I tried to use QGIS to create voronoi polygons from a set of points with an attribute (`group`) and then merge the polygons with the same value for that attribute. (This last step is what QGIS calls Dissolve.) It worked in principle, but since [the built-in voronoi algorithm produces erroneous output](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/8002), I am trying alternatives, especially ST_VoronoiPolygons.

I managed to load a table of points (`my_points`) into PostgreSQL. It has a `geom` column (automatically created for PostGIS) and a `group` column.

I read that I should use the following commands:

```
drop table if exists voronoi_output;
create table voronoi_output as
    select ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom))) from my_points;
```

But the newly created table `voronoi_output` is missing the `group` column, which is needed for the next step (dissolve). How can this be fixed?

(If `ST_VoronoiPolygons` would accept polylines as input, I could just feed it a bunch of polylines instead of "groups" of points. Then the "dissolve" step would not be needed), but I do not expect that to work.)

Comment: did those queries help? I was still typing on my phone when @JGH already answered...we had pretty much the same solution, but he/she was first. seeing both answers, you should probably combine them: while the `JOIN` is supposed to be the preferred way to cross-reference two tables, the `ST_Within` supposedly performs better than `ST_Intersects`. I would also recommend to perform the 'dissolve' as part of the query.

Answer (score 4):

You need to reassign the *group* ids to the polygons. You could

```
   CREATE TABLE voronoi_output AS
     SELECT points.group,
            polys.geom
     FROM (
       SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom))).geom AS geom
       FROM my_points
     ) AS polys
     JOIN my_points AS points
       ON ST_Intersects(points.geom, polys.geom);
```

to simply do that, or

```
    CREATE TABLE voronoi_output AS
      SELECT points.group,
             ST_Collect(polys.geom) AS geom  -- or ST_Union(...) here; returns merged
      FROM (                                 -- POLYGONS where possible, but is slower
        SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom AS geom
        FROM my_points
      ) AS polys
      JOIN my_points AS points
        ON ST_Intersects(points.geom, polys.geom)
      GROUP BY points.group;
```

to actually get the 'dissolved' multipolygons grouped by the *group* id.

Comment: I combined the answers from you and @JGH as suggested into the answer that I just posted.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to spatially associate the points to the polygons.

```
create table voronoi_output as
SELECT geom, my_points.group 
FROM (
     SELECT(ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(a.geom)))).geom as geom 
        FROM my_points a) as voronoi,
      my_points b
WHERE st_within(b.geom, voronoi.geom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers from ThingumaBob and JGH gives

```
create table voronoi_output as
select ST_Union(voronoi.geom), my_points.group from
    (select (ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom as geom 
     from my_points) as voronoi,
    my_points
where ST_Within(my_points.geom, voronoi.geom)
group by my_points.group;
```

[image]